# Pronunciation of final consonants in the history of English

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics

When in the history of the english language did the consonants begin to be pronounced as a glottal stop? I notice this phenomenon is more prevalent in American English at the end of words but sometimes I notice it in British English, in the cockney pronunciation of *bottle* and *water* and slightly less frequently at the end of words.

Was this something that happened also in Middle English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has to divide the phenomenon of glottalisation into its different forms. Intervocalic T-glottalisation is the classic defining feature of a whole host of English varieties, mostly from Britain, and there are several candidates:

- East Anglia, specifically Norfolk. Studies done in the 1950s on local residents born in the **1870s** [suggest that](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=s1CeDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA132) the T was glottalised back then.
- Cockney. Very influential, and [possibly *the* driver](http://repository.essex.ac.uk/16806/1/PhD%20Thesis_Library%20%28Badia%20Barrera%29.pdf) of the modern trend towards glottalisation across urban areas across Britain, although its influence might be hyped. This is well attested in the **mid-19th century** through the eye dialect of certain famous novels.
- Glasgow. Glaswegian English is stated to have used the glottal stop [since](http://digital.library.leeds.ac.uk/392/1/LSE_1999_pp181-204_Stuart-Smith_article.pdf) the **19th century** in word-medial and word-final positions.

As for *final* glottalisation, that's something less well explored.

- Barbados seems to have developed it separately, as it [only affects /t/ in final position](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8sDLCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA584#v=onepage&q&f=false), and in the Caribbean it is identified with Barbados exclusively.
- New York glottalises /t/ at the ends of syllables but not intervocalically. 19th century intervocalic glottalisation [was reported](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8sDLCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA515), but does not seem to have survived intact.

I haven't seen any reports on Middle English glottalisation, and it's not altogether clear whether Shakespeare used it, although [there are possible indications](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73645/rhyme-in-elizabethan-sonnets) that the Original Pronunciation movement like to pick up on.